# Android Error to change Activity after using Fragment

Tags: android

I have this error after adding some fragments, in the app I have a button that directs me to another layout before this if it worked.

This code directed me to the respective class

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_favorite:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Favorites.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;

            case R.id.contacto:
                Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, contacto.class);
                startActivity(i1);
                finish();
                return true;


            case R.id.about:
                Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Bio.class);
                startActivity(i2);
                finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

They are activities

```
package com.niccode.pets.menu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import com.niccode.pets.R;
import com.niccode.pets.javamail.JavaMail;

public class contacto extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nombre;
    EditText email;
    EditText mensaje;
    Button enviar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacto);

        Toolbar     toolbar;
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        if(toolbar !=   null ){
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        nombre     = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombreCon);
        email      = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        mensaje    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mensaje);
        enviar     = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.send);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendMail();
            }
        });

    }

    private void sendMail() {
        String subject  = nombre.getText().toString();
        String mail     = email.getText().toString();
        String body     = mensaje.getText().toString();

        JavaMail sendmail = new JavaMail(this, mail, subject , body);
        sendmail.execute();

    }

}
```

```
package com.niccode.pets;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.niccode.pets.adaptador.Mascotas_Adaptador;
import com.niccode.pets.constructor.Mascotas;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Favorites extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String likes;
    private RecyclerView listaMascotas;



    ArrayList<Mascotas> ArraylistMascotas = new ArrayList<Mascotas>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorites);

        Toolbar     toolbar;
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        if(toolbar !=   null ){
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        listaMascotas = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvMascotasFv);
        LinearLayoutManager vista = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        vista.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        listaMascotas.setLayoutManager(vista);
        iniciarLista();
        iniciarAdaptador();

    }


    public void iniciarLista() {

        ArraylistMascotas.add(new Mascotas(R.drawable.gatito1, "Shasha", 1));
        ArraylistMascotas.add(new Mascotas(R.drawable.gatito2, "Nugget", 2));
        ArraylistMascotas.add(new Mascotas(R.drawable.gatito3, "Michin", 3));
        ArraylistMascotas.add(new Mascotas(R.drawable.gatito4, "Pelusa", 4));
        ArraylistMascotas.add(new Mascotas(R.drawable.gatito5, "Misifu", 5));

    }

    public void iniciarAdaptador(){
        Mascotas_Adaptador adaptador = new Mascotas_Adaptador(ArraylistMascotas);
        listaMascotas.setAdapter(adaptador);

    }

}
```

```
package com.niccode.pets.menu;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.niccode.pets.R;

public class Bio extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bio);
        Toolbar mybar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mybar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        Toolbar     toolbar;
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);

        mybar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        if(toolbar !=   null ){
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
    }

}
```

I have this error en logcat, when I try to change the layout

```
07-02 15:45:33.590 2727-2727/com.niccode.pets W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d01930)
07-02 15:45:33.600 2727-2727/com.niccode.pets E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.niccode.pets/com.niccode.pets.Favorites}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.niccode.pets.Favorites.onCreate(Favorites.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5131)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
07-02 15:45:37.050 2727-2727/com.niccode.pets I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2727 SIG: 9
```

I used this code in to add the toolbar in each class.

```
 Toolbar     toolbar;
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        if(toolbar !=   null ){
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
```

I also organized my project as follows

[image]

Comment: Are Favorites, Contacto and Bio activities or fragments ? 
could you show us Favorites class

Comment: they are Activities

Comment: it says NullPointerException in Favorites in line 32 in the Crash log.

Comment: You are trying to access the same toolbar in all activities. Probably you are setting content view but that layout doesn't contain R.id.my_toolbar. You should add toolbar to every activities differently.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```